# ObjectMapper text preprocessing before deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I want to deserialize a JSON file, which contains placeholders ${PLACEHOLDER_NAME} which I want to replace by values. The classes I need to deserialize may vary, using a module for a specific class is not a convenient option. Is there any way, how to do a text preprocessing before deserialization?

Comment: I think question is not clear. Why a straight forward solution wouldn't work? I.e. read your file into memory as String replace placeholders with values and than parse Json with ObjectMapper by giving it class name and the Json String

Comment: Because there are more places, where I'm using this functionality and the code would be duplicated. I can create my own class, but that's also not good enough, because it wouldn't implement any common interface with ObjectMapper, because ObjectMapper is a class and not interface.

Comment: If you are using Spring you can just override the ObjectMapper bean and do what @MichaelGantman suggested, albeit without implementing a new class.